# Remove entries from Map after comparing keys from a Set

Tags: java, collections

I've one `Map<Long, String>` & one `Set<Long>`.

Say,

```
Map<Long, String> mapA
Set<Long> setB
```

I want to remove those entries from `mapA`, whose keys are not in `setB`.

Also I want to print log for all the entries which have been removed from `mapA`.

Currently I'm using iterator.

```
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Long, String>> iterator = mapA.entrySet().iterator();
     iterator.hasNext(); ) {

    Map.Entry<Long, String> entry = iterator.next();
    if (!setB.contains(entry.getKey())) {
        
        LOGGER.error(entry.getKey() + " does not exist");

        // Removing from map.
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

How can I do it more concisely using Java8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use streams like this;

```
mapA.entrySet().removeIf(e -> {
    if(setB.contains(e.getKey())){
        return true;
    }
    LOGGER.error(e.getKey() + " does not exist");
    return false;
});
```

Or mush better you can call the keySet, if you don't need the values:

```
mapA.keySet().removeIf(k -> {
    if (setB.contains(k)) {
        return true;
    }
    LOGGER.error(k + " does not exist");
    return false;
});
```